# Soundflower change output through terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, audio, soundflower

So I'm running soundflower to be able to control the volume for my monitor.

I was writing a script that toggles display mirroring, and when I'm mirroring displays I want the audio to come out of my laptop's built in speakers, when I'm not mirroring displays I want the audio to come out of my Monitor's output.

This script is working fine, but when turning off display mirroring, my monitor's sound gets bugged, and the way to solve it is to manually change the output on Soundflower 2ch.
I tried searching (a lot) for terminal commands for either soundflower or soundflowerbed but couldn't find anything.

Anyone knows how to automate this? Even applescript would work if I can't do it through terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running? What version of Soundflower? Soundflowerbed hasn't been working properly [or been updated] since about Mavericks.

Comment: Running 11.6 (20G165), Not sure about SoundFlower but might be 2.0b2, SoundFlowerBed 2.0.0

Comment: hmm, yup, both about 7 years old, though Sf itself was correctly signed to run in Big Sur, SfB wasn't. tbh, I was surprised you even got it to run. I honestly don't know how to achieve what you need, I'm afraid.